# Load Photo Library iOS 14 With Limited Access

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have an app that takes pictures that are stored in the photos library. I would like to be able to load just the images taken with the app into an app library .I have two functions that load the photos library and then request an individual image. The images are requested in a foreach loop. That works fine with full access. However, with limited access I get nothing. If I use the photo picker I get the pictures selected.

My retrieval code is:

```
func loadLibrary() {
    
    let fetchOptions = PHFetchOptions()
    fetchOptions.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "creationDate",ascending: false)]
    fetchOptions.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "mediaType = %d", PHAssetMediaType.image.rawValue)
    
    assets = PHAsset.fetchAssets(with: fetchOptions)
}

func loadImage(_ asset: PHAsset) -> UIImage? {
    var image: UIImage? = nil

    let option = PHImageRequestOptions()
    option.isSynchronous = true
    option.isNetworkAccessAllowed = true
    option.resizeMode = .fast

    manager.requestImage(for: asset, targetSize: PHImageManagerMaximumSize, contentMode: .aspectFill, options: option) { img, err  in
        guard let img = img else { return }
            image = img
    }
    return image

}
```

My saving code:

```
final class ImageSaver: NSObject, ObservableObject {
    
    public static let shared = ImageSaver()
    
    let objectDidChange = PassthroughSubject<Void, Never>()
    
    @Published var saved = false {
        didSet {
            if saved {
                objectDidChange.send()
            }
        }
    }

    func writeToPhotoAlbum(image: UIImage) {
        UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, self, #selector(saveError), nil)
    }

    @objc func saveError(_ image: UIImage, didFinishSavingWithError error: Error?, contextInfo: UnsafeRawPointer) {
        if let error = error {
            print("Image not saved. Error: \(error)")
            self.saved = false
        } else {
        print("Save finished!")
            self.saved = true
        }
    }
}
```

In the WWDC2020 Session Video [Handle the Limited Photos Library in your app](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2020/10641/?time=672) the video states that "When your app creates new assets they will automatically be included as part of the user's selection for the application." This is exactly the behavior I want, but it is not the behavior I am getting. Changing the privacy settings shows the fetch and load are working as expected.

Comment: You're probably saving the photos wrong. Add the write code to your question and maybe we can spot what.

Comment: Also, sync fetching a high amount of images in maximum resolution will crash your app at some point

Comment: Edited. I was considering the max resolution for later. Currently it is displayed in a LazyVStack.

Comment: Okay, you're gonna have to do it the hard way. The UIImage way bypasses asking for write permission by not giving you read permission. The proper way for you is using the PHAssetChangeRequest thingy.

Comment: As to image fetching, I suggest maintaining the photos manager and loading each image as the lazy view appears on screen, instead of prefetching all at once. Also obiously don't fetch in larger than needed size (which is frame * screen.scale)

Comment: Not helpless, but I have a question about `PHAssetCollectionChangeRequest(for:)` That is a change request for an album that takes a fetchRequest that I presume is the contents of that album. In dealing with limited authorization, I can't create (or save into?) albums. From that same session "User albums however cannot be fetched, nor created." What the heck do I put in as the fetch request for a non-existent album? And you are correct about the lack of tutorials. Add to that the fact that Apple left a lot of frameworks around...

Comment: With regard tot he image fetching, thank you for the tidbit about frame * screen.scale. I figured it was something along those lines, but hadn't gotten there yet. One less thing to research...

Comment: You aren't storing Photos in a way that can be synced, so I assume you only need them locally. If so, just store the image as data in your documents directory. Fetch it when you need it. Using Photos as a local image host is not intended. If users would still like to keep a copy in Photos.app, you can use the UIImage save way. Just load it from your local directory insted of from PH.

Comment: In my app I store all fetched Photos locally (and in a cloud), instead of relying on AssetIDs. Having them in the local file system also enables you to do the optimised CGImageSourceCreateThumbnailAtIndex image fetching trick if you have a lot of images.

Comment: Here's how I implemented that if you need one. https://pastebin.com/fikrLmXd

Comment: I actually do want them to be shareable and to sync. Being able to send them to others is part of the plan. I will check out your link, but it sounds like the better part of valor will be full access and save it to my own folder. I thought I could use the privacy restrictions as a feature to make it simpler AND get less entitlement. Thanks.